# Default to original language in nodes list

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I set up a multilingual blog with Drupal 8 (in English and Chinese), I want to list articles according to current language in the front page.

However, if an article does not has an translation in the current language, I want it to default to **the original untranslated version(whatever language)**, with a hint like "This content is not available in Chinese, we are showing the original article in English."

Assuming that I have 3 blog articles (nodes), with or without translation:

- Article 1 (original language: English; translated to: Chinese)
- Article 2 (original language: Chinese; translated to: English)
- Article 3 (original language: English)

When a user visits the English front page at `example.com/en`, they will see:

- Article 1 (in English, original)
- Article 2 (in English, translated)
- Article 3 (in English, original)

which is the default behaviour of Drupal 8.

---

Now, when a user visits the Chinese front page at `example.com/zh-hans`, **I would like them to see**:

- Article 1 (in Chinese, translated)
- Article 2 (in Chinese, original)
- Article 3 (**in English, with a hint**)

However, Drupal 8 out of the box will display:

- Article 1 (in Chinese, translated)
- Article 2 (in Chinese, original)

---

I tried editing the front page as it is a view in Drupal 8, but with the filters in view I could not achieve this.

[image: Language filter in view]

(Filters in view)

Do I need to implement a custom filter for the front page view? Please suggest where should I start, I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Radium, have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

See the solution to [How do I get Views content items in "my language" but fall back to "default" if the content isn't translated?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192782/how-do-i-get-views-content-items-in-my-language-but-fall-back-to-default-if) whether it helps just by configuring in admin. It seems to solve the same problem.

Unfortunately, I have the same problem, and I can't get the solution described there to work. Reading all the issues linked in [meta Make multilingual views work](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313159), it seems to me that there is no built-in solution. I tried to implement a `hook_views_post_execute()` and to filter the `ViewExecutable $view` manually, like in the following, but it did not work - either still shows multiple translations per entity, or entities are missing:

```
# File modules/contrib/modulename/modulename.module
# Enabled in admin/extend
function modulename_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view)
{
  $contentLangcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();

  # trying either one of:
  # $Filtered = filterLangcodeOrEn($contentLangcode, $view->result);
  $Filtered = filterNodeOnce($view->result);

  $view->result = $Filtered;
  $view->total_rows = count($Filtered);
}

function filterNodeOnce($rows)
{
  $Nodes = array();
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $Nodes[$row->nid] = $row;
  }

  return array_values($Nodes);
}

function filterLangcodeOrEn($contentLangcode, $rows)
{
  # group by nid
  $EntitiesLangcodesRow = array();
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $EntitiesLangcodesRow[$row->nid][$row->node_field_data_langcode] = $row;
  }

  # select
  $Filtered = array();
  foreach ($EntitiesLangcodesRow as $LangcodesRow) {
    if (isset($LangcodesRow[$contentLangcode])) {
      $Filtered[] = $LangcodesRow[$contentLangcode];
    }
    else if (isset($LangcodesRow["en"])) {
      $Filtered[] = $LangcodesRow["en"];
    }
  }
  return $Filtered;
}
```