# Webform module loosing language for referenced options

Tags: views, 8, nodes, webforms, i18n-l10n

First I have content type "Quiz option" which is translatable.

Then I have a view that returns Entity references of that type. For language option I selected "Content language of view row" and also added filter "Content: Translation language = interface text language selected for page".

I translated (to German - original language is English) only one content of that entity and when I test view on view edit page it works well:

If I'm editing view on English view edit page I see all the content on English, except that German one. And when I'm editing view on German view edit page (with that "de" in path prefix) I see only one entity - the translated one and it's title is displayed well, on German.
So far, so good.

Now I have a webform with some select button where for options I'm using reference mode with that view for selecting elements. And on front-end I  always see content title on English? Why is that?
So on front-end if I'm on German page I see only one option - the translated one, but it's title is on English, not on German?!?

I tried removing language filter I mentioned above and then I see all the options, but again they are all on English.

So, when I test view everything seems fine and when editing webform field I have only option for selecting the view (and passing the parameters), but nothing related to language.

And even if i.e. I force strictly German as "Rendering language" in views options I still see my options on English on front-end.

Any idea why I'm getting entity titles in default language (English) instead of in language of the current page (German)?

Comment: This is probably an issue for entity reference select views displays in general, not only in webforms: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273654/view-display-plugin-entity-reference-not-using-translation

Comment: Hmm..yes I saw that question and even commented it. But there's no solution for that issue. Right?

Comment: I've just wanted to connect both questions and express my doubts this has anything to do with Webform.

Comment: Sure, thank you for that.

Comment: @4k4 where do you think is the problem? I would like to check if there's an open issue for that or open it if there isn't.

Comment: Comparing ViewsSelection::getReferenceableEntities with TermSelection::getReferenceableEntities, the Views version does not translate the entities before returning the entity labels: `\Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($entity);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97676/discussion-between-milang-and-4k4).

Comment: Just tried and what @4k4 said is true. So is this a bug or what? How should this be solved?

Comment: I don't know. While there is specifically a row plugin to compose the fields inline, which would also allow to configure the translation in UI, the result is not used. It seems more like this feature (providing select lists via Views) is not ready yet.

Comment: By commenting on this recent question I've found out it will be ready very soon https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284693/entity-reference-view-fails-after-update-to-drupal-8-7-6

Comment: Good to hear that.