# Entity Reference View fails after update to drupal 8.7.6

Tags: views, 8

Recently I updated my drupal site from `8.6.14` to `8.7.6`.

A previously-working Entity Reference View display that is connected to a form Autocomplete field stopped working.
The spinning circle keeps spinning and does not match user input to an entity.
(The ER View display concatenates a user email address and his company name for easier user selection : ie "joe@smith.com - Smith Plumbing, Inc." )

Error in log is:

> Error: Class 'Drupal\views\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\Xss' not found in Drupal\views\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\ViewsSelection->stripAdminAndAnchorTagsFromResults() (line 272 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chapter6/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/EntityReferenceSelection/ViewsSelection.php)

I added `use Drupal\Components\Utility\XSS` to *ViewSelection.php* and now the error is

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\views\ViewExecutable could not be converted to string in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAutocompleteMatcher->getMatches() (line 69 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chapter6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityAutocompleteMatcher.php)

Has anyone else experienced this in latest drupal 8?

Comment: You've installed a patch from this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2174633, which obviously no longer applies.

Comment: Thank you, yes.  I had applied patch drupal/issues/2174633#238 last February.  Had to remove that and apply drupal/issues/2174633#323 to drupal 8.7.6 to get it working.  All is well.